# Does Nancy model bind to fields as per the documentation or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nancy

I have tried a really simple Nancy example for model binding and the documentation (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding) says that fields are just as usable as properties, but in practice they only seem to bind when I use properties.

Is the documentation right (if so, why isn't my model binding?) or is the documentation wrong (if so, why?)

Comment: Based on my experience, it only binds to properties - I've accidentally left the get and set out before and wondered why it wasn't binding. No idea why the docs say otherwise. Will confirm with the source code later.

Comment: Just as an additional hint for those who use properties: Don't forget to define a setter, like I did! You won't get an error thrown. :)

Answer (score 0):

Model binding to fields wasn't supported [until v1](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1613). As long as you're using v1 or newer this should work out of the box. If it doesn't could you provide some code that reproduces the issue along with the version of Nancy you're using?

Since the documentation targets the most recent version it can be confusing as to which features are supported in each version. At the moment the best place to find version information for changes like this is on the [breaking changes page](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Breaking-Changes).

Comment: Model binding works fine as long as I use properties. My question was regarding fields specifically.